# Mysql access to hack website

Tags: security

I had a recent incident where an old dev who helped write code for a site from India out of the blue asked to give him work and unknowingly I didn't realize that what he wanted was cpanel access. I've had bad experiences hiring online through freelancer by releasing cpanel creds. So this developer got one up on me I think because a few weeks back an old colleagues brother did correct the issue on the site which after that dev from India messaged me out of the blue for work wanted cpanel access but I don't give him so he wanted all the files in compressed folder and I didn't think it would come back to bite me but the database.php file in config had my db user and password. My question is can the dev use this files info to access my site remotely. I also used to make sure to delete any remote connections with mysql remote through cpanel. It shows an IP address that connected remotely. And ever since I've also changed the PW on database.php in config.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the dev use this files to access my site remotely.

It depends - most likely the answer is **yes**. You said that he got the MySQL login details - the server, username, password and database name. With these, he can log into your *database* from *anywhere*, as he can just connect to your database server and auth with those credentials.

So, what can he do from there? Practically any database-related task.

- He could delete your database, or your tables (but this is the worse option, as it doesn't really achieve much for him - you probably have backups. Also, it is very obvious);
- If there's text in the database that gets `echo`ed out onto the user's screens, he could add in his own HTML / JavaScript in there, and potentially redirect them to another site that looks similar (they won't notice) and scam them for their passwords, or add something to your site that could make users no longer trust your it, etc.
- If the database contains a list of emails / addresses / phone numbers / usernames / un-hashed passwords he could sell those on to third parties.

### So, what can you do?

***Change your database user password immediately!!!*** If you have multiple MySQL users, I would recommend changing their passwords, too.

To prevent against the second attack that I mentioned (code injection), roll back the database to before he got the files (if possible).

A roll back would also fix anything he could have deleted, etc, so this essentially fixes attacks 1 and 2.

As for attack 3, he could have exported the whole database by now, so there's not much you can do. If you store your user's passwords in plain text (you shouldn't), let them know, and make them change their password wherever they have used it on other sites.

### Could he have accessed other parts of my site (cPanel, the actual code, etc)?

Not unless you used the same password for the cPanel login as you did for the MySQL user. If you did, change that password immediately too, and maybe roll back the whole site to before he got access.

### Has he actually done any of this?

Maybe. There is the chance he just wanted to work on your site, and didn't actually do anything malicious. Then again, he could have tried any of the things that I've discussed. There's not really any way to know.

Comment: I took the steps above haven't rolled back. The main reason is he didn't have same password in db.php for cpanel no root access to cpanel although I think he just inticked one of 4 choices in phpmyadmin for update, select, insert, delete. I can't seem to find the menu tab for this in my db and im no good at sql commands just HTML. Where is this menu because I'm not receiving my email registration link which had already been fixed by pre dev not India.